# 8 Directional Character Spritesheet Generator

Tags: game-design, sprites, character

I've searched for the past hour and didn't find anything worth looking.

I'm creating a game, and I'm just starting. I found [this site](http://gaurav.munjal.us/Universal-LPC-Spritesheet-Character-Generator/) to help me create my characters, but I want something to create characters with 8 directions, instead of just 4. Are there any of these online?

I don't need the animation part for now, just the 8 direction sprites

Comment: I'm confused... too broad? I think that an answer to this question would be some useful tools to help character creation. Am I wrong? How can I make this question "less broad"?

Comment: Questions like this that ask for "tools that perform some task" are considered too broad since they're just list-generation questions for which it's impractical for there to be a single objective answer (see the [help] for what is on/off topic). This sort of question is better asked on an actual discussion forum like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).